# what's the waiting time for the biometric appoinment?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

Can anyone tell me what's the waiting time for the biometric appoinment? I sent my application for a residence card as a non EU direct family member. It's been two weeks already and I haven't received any news from them not even the letter for the biometric appointment. I think when I receive it, I will feel better. At least I will know what's going on. Plus right now I can't work, so it makes longer the wait.

Comment: It might depend on which visa application centre you are going to visit. Could you include that in your question, please? As a data point, I used the Toronto UK visa application centre recently and I had no problem getting an appointment on a day that was convenient for me. They keep their appointment calendar open on a sliding window about one month into the future.